# Isomorphism of finite groups and cycle graphs

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be finite groups and suppose they do have the same cycle graph. Is it possible to argue that this implies $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic? If yes, why? If not, is there an explicit counterexample?

I can't come up with a counterexample, at least for small orders, but I also am not naively convinced that this statement holds in general. Rephrasing, do there exist two non-ismorphic finite groups $G$ and $H$ with identical cycle graph?

Second question, does the above statement hold true if we restrict to finite simple groups?

Thank you.

Comment: Cycle graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph_(algebra). Hint: think of groups with prime exponent.

Comment: As regards the simple case, there are lists of simple groups of the same order, so you should try, and say what you have tried and where you're stuck. It would better take place in MathSE, I believe.